# How to include a .yaml in Python3.8 package distribution

Tags: python, setup.py, software-distribution

My directory structure is as follows:

```
global_toolkit/
    - setup.py
    - MANIFEST.in
    ... 
    - global_toolkit/
        - main.py
        - protocol.yaml
        ...
```

The package is hosted using pypi-server and then installed by a service using pip. protocol.yaml is not in the distribution:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/global_toolkit/protocol.yaml'
```

My MAINFEST.in (I've seen different formats on different tutorials. I tried them all...)

```
include global_toolkit/*.yaml
include *.yaml
recursive-include global_toolkit *
```

I've also tried to use setup.py:

```
files = ["global_toolkit/*"]

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=['global_toolkit'],
    package_data = {'global_toolkit': files},
    ...
```

It's difficult to figure out what isn't working here. Help appreciated.

Comment: `package_data = {'global_toolkit': '*.yaml'}` -- https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html

Comment: You now have to put the files to include in a list, and to include all files in subdirectories use `package_data={'global_toolkit': ['**/*.yml']}`

Comment: How do I do this in pyproject.toml?